# Creating an Apache Virtual Directory, but updating Active Directory DNS

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, active-directory, virtualhost

I'm just getting started with using the Zend Framework and am following a recommended procedure where I am supposed to create an Apache Virtual Directory for the public-facing portion of a new Zend project.  I don't THINK I had any issues creating the Virtual Directory, but my knowledge of the required DNS changes is rather lacking.  The dev server I'm using is on a Microsoft Windows Active Directory domain, so I've added A records for both the server name and the subdomain.  Still, trying to browse to the site from a Windows 7 PC isn't working properly.  What am I missing?  What's the proper set of steps for getting an Apache-served subdomain to appear properly in a peer computer's web browser?  Details below:

- server: Debian command-line only, freshly installed today with Zend Server CE LAMP stack
- server name: ZENDEV
- subdomain: SQUARE.ZENDEV
- AD Domain functional level: 2008 mixed (run by a mishmash of 03 and 08 servers)
- attempting to visit the sites: http://square.zendev and http://square.zendev.domain.local (name of domain redacted, but using the local (not com) suffix)

Apache Virtual Directory added to httpd.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/square/public"
ServerName square.localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

Is this only a problem with DNS?  Or with DNS *and* my Virtual Directory?

Answer (score 0):

Create a zendev zone in your AD DNS. 
Create an A record within that zone called "square" and point it at the IP address of your server.

In the apache config change `ServerName square.localhost` to `ServerName square.zendev`

This is all assuming that your computer resolves DNS via the Active Directory nameservers.

Comment: Ah!  I just figured it out right before you answered. (see my comment, below).  Turns out I did properly by making the A records manually in ADDNS, but ruined the Apache declaration.  Thanks very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, after a little more fiddling around, I noticed my issue.  It was leaving "square.localhost" as the ServerName in my Apache declaration...I should have used "square.zendev".  Thanks anyway!